Do second language learners, at times, perceive the language to be acquired as more quiet or more difficult to hear when uttered, volume independent?
Has any person experienced the perceived lowering of volume or difficulty in hearing (perception of increased noise, for example) when attempting to listen to a second language?  Is the effect observed in all language learners?  Why or why not?

It looks like a subconscious delusion that one's inability to make out the language is mainly due to poor quality of the sound and not because of one's insufficient experience in making out that language spoken. From my personal language learning experience I'd recommend starting with audio of medium to low quality so as to get used to all kinds of audio distractions which are always there in real life. There's a better SE to ask a question like that and have a detailed answer, it's Language Learning SE, https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/

I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to Language Learning SE https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/

When you first hear a language, you mostly can't hear it. It's sound jumbled together. You need a way in. That's comes by starting to learn some things in the language. As for volume, this is not an issue for most people unless they already have hearing issues.
